# How to let my docusaurus navbar transparent

Tags: navbar

How to let my docusaurus navbar transparent?
like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJq31.jpg

How to let my docusaurus navbar transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

inside `src/custom.css` file, just add following code:

```css
/* .. */
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Uh,I got this error : ERROR] ValidationError: "navbar.style" must be one of [dark, primary]

Comment: @ssangyongsports I've just modified it sorry for the previous answer :(